# How to synchronize more than one IIS web servers

Tags: iis, web-applications, deployment, webserver

I have a .net web application, I want to host the app into more than one IIS web servers. The web servers must synchronized so if one web server is down than the others should respond to user requests.

Comment: Tools like Web Deploy can be used to sync configuration and web contents, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/synchronize-iis

Comment: you could use iis web farm load balancing. you can configure more than one iis server with a web farm and host same application or site on that web farm server and use load balancing.[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-hosting/scenario-build-a-web-farm-with-iis-servers/overview-build-a-web-farm-with-iis-servers)

Answer (score 0):

Check out tools like:
[gtg.dk](https://gtg.dk)
[deploybot.com](https://deploybot.com)

Answer (score 0):

Check out also [deployplace](https://deployplace.com) it is very similar to DeployBot, but much more powerful and allows to deploy complicated application. It's still in beta, but there is a free plan.